# Excel VBA - select an .xlsm file from which to copy the values of some cells and paste them into the workbook you are working on

Tags: excel

I need help from someone more experienced than me!
I'm working on a master worksheet in which I would like to collect data from other worksheet. I need that when I press the macro button on the master:
**1** - Application.GetOpenFilename - a window will open in which I have to select the .xlsm file from which I want to copy the data
**2** - Copy from the opened file the value of cells V2:X2 and AC2:AI2
**3** - Paste those values on the row of the master table in which are matched the values of column B ("0000") and C ("00") of the table and cell T2 and U2 of the opened file
**4** - cells V2:X2 will correspond to cell D:F and cells AC2:AI2 to cell K:P

I wasn't able to find any other similar question, I will appreciate your help!

Kind regards

Luca

Comment: This might be a good starting point: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-open-copy-paste-and-close.828654/

Comment: Thank you Paul for the link, I read it but unfortunately it miss the match for finding the right row of the master in which past the copied cells. Hope in sombody who will help me. Regards L